# Magento 2 : How to Clear Previous Messages in MessageManager

Tags: magento2, messages

I have added a below line in my observer file for the event checkout_cart_save_after

```
$this->_messageManager->addNotice(__("A Notice Message"));
```

Every time it hits observer, it displayes more than 1 message in frontend. I need to display only one message at a time. Can anyone pls help to clear the messages in message manager?

My observer logic is below:

```
 public function execute(Observer $observer)
    {
        allowCheckout = 1;
          //custom logic......
         if($allowCheckout == 0){
           $this->_messageManager->addNotice(__("A Notice Message"));

         }

    }
```

So Everytime when the event occurs it goes to observer and displays message manager notice message. It displays more than one message. I want only once the message to be displayed

Comment: Can you share your code of observer, what you have try?

Comment: @Dhiren Vasoya. I have updated my question with observer code

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Try the following code:

```
$this->_messageManager->getMessages(true); //this will clear your messageManager container
$this->_messageManager->addNotice(__("A Notice Message"));
```

Answer (score 0):

Try it with CookieManager.

```
public function __construct(
        \Magento\Framework\Stdlib\CookieManagerInterface $cookieManager
    )
    {
        $this->cookieManager = $cookieManager;
    }



$this->cookieManager->deleteCookie('mage-messages');
```